# Using Assigned Variable to Fetch Data from df

Tags: dataframe, variables, fetch

If I have a variable, x, assigned to an attribute 'a' retrieved from data frame A, is there a way to pull a different attribute from data frame B, where x and attribute 'b' are in the same row in data frame ?

dfprofile = pd.DataFrame(data2)
x=dfprofile["sector"]

dfprofile is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, as is dfsectorpe below

data stored as object class?

In this instance, x = ‘Technology’, but the value of x will change based on user input of stock symbol.

dfsectorpe lists pe ratios for all sectors.  I want to retrieve the pe ratio for ‘x’ sector to compare it to the pe ratio for a given stock.

I believe I have tried at least forty different ways, probably around eight variations of five different ways, including, .at, .iat, .loc, .iloc, ,get, a function I wrote, etc.
Returned all sorts of interesting errors, including type errors.
Sometimes, pandas will return the entire df, with all values. Sometimes, the value: None. The main problem appears to be that, although it is clear that ‘Technology’ has a pe ratio, I have retrieved it a few different ways using ‘Technology’ itself instead of x, when x is substituted, pandas does not discover that value; in fact, pandas believes the df is empty

Tried everything, all methods, researched github  and stackoverflow and internet

Comment: As written, answer to your question is "no". A variable assigned to a value will never give you a different value. If you want to look up a value in two different dataframes, you need the "lookup" parameters - that might be a "row" and/or "column" (so to speak - such as return all data from the first row), or it might be a filter criteria (such as returning data that has a type of "Technology"). I am speaking very vaguely here ... you need to provide an example of what you want to do (with sample dataframes A and B ideally) to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: I put print statements in to show results of the last method I tried:
print(dfsectorpe.get(["sector", "pe"]))
ser = dfsectorpe["pe"]
print(ser.get(dfsectorpe['sector']))
print(ser.get("Technology"))

0          Basic Materials   17.622023820911426
1   Communication Services   10.416651527328115
.....
12              Technology  -13.248754026663573
13               Utilities    22.85753635884015
None
None